# how to intent in recyclerview when we click on image

Tags: android, android-layout

So,basically in this as soon as I will click on the image view i should go on the next page that is firstpage .IN this for firstpage I have used recyclerview and for the introduction pge i have used gridadapter.but when I click on the imag view its not getting intented to the next page.I tried all possible sols. ut still the same.plzz help.

this is my introduction.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
    tools:context=".MainActivity2">


    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="199dp"
        android:layout_height="199dp"
        app:cardElevation="10dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        app:contentPadding="10dp"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.247"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="35dp">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="193dp"
            android:layout_height="194dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                android:layout_width="143dp"
                android:layout_height="109dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="7dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp"
                tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars"
                android:onClick="image"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView15"
                android:layout_width="158dp"
                android:layout_height="33dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:text="text"
                android:textColor="@color/DarkBlue"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.2"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/imageView4" />


        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

this is my MainActivity2.java code

```
public abstract class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity implements ClickedListener {
    RecyclerView recycleview1;
    List<String> titles;
    List<Integer>images;
    GridAdapter adapter;
    ImageView image;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.intropage);


        recycleview1 = findViewById(R.id.recycleview1);

        titles = new ArrayList<>();
        images = new ArrayList<>();

        titles.add("LATEST MOVIES");
        titles.add("UPCOMING MOVIES");
        titles.add("TRENDING MOVIES");
        titles.add("NOW PLAYING");
        titles.add("RELEASED MOVIES");
        titles.add("HINDI MOVIES");
        titles.add("MARATHI MOVIES");
        titles.add("ENGLISH MOVIES");
        titles.add("TELUGU MOVIES");
        titles.add("TAMIL MOVIES");


        images.add(R.drawable.latestmovie);
        images.add(R.drawable.upcomingmovies);
        images.add(R.drawable.trendingmovie);
        images.add(R.drawable.nowplaying);
        images.add(R.drawable.releasedmovie);
        images.add(R.drawable.hindimovies);
        images.add(R.drawable.marathimovies);
        images.add(R.drawable.englishmovies);
        images.add(R.drawable.telugumovies);
        images.add(R.drawable.tamilmovies);


        adapter =  new GridAdapter(this,titles,images,this);

        GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this,2,GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
        recycleview1.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
        recycleview1.setAdapter(adapter);


    }


    @Override
    public void onPictureClicked() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity2.this, MainActivity1.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

this is my GridAdapter.java code

```
public class GridAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GridAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    List<String>titles;
    List<Integer>images;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public GridAdapter(Context context,List<String>titles,List<Integer>images){
        this.titles = titles;
        this.images = images;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.intoduction,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.titles.setText(titles.get(position));
        holder.images.setImageResource(images.get(position));

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return titles.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView titles;
        ImageView images;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            titles = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView15);
            images = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
        }
    }
}
```

this is my firstpage.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/LightGrey"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity1">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold">

        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
            android:text="Description"
            android:textSize="20sp">

        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="Ratings"
            android:textSize="20sp">

        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RecyclerView onClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471109/recyclerview-onclick)

Answer (score 1):

This `interface` will be implemented in `class` where your adapter is called.

I created an interface and implemented in MainActivity2, that interface has on override() method `clickedListener`. This `clickedListener` will be called whenever an image clicked and then the intent inside `clickedListener` will be called and you will be moved to `MainActivity1.java`.

This is your working code.

```
   public interface ClickedListener {
    
        void onPictureClicked();
     
    }
```

**GridAdapter.java**

```
public class GridAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GridAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    List<String>titles;
    List<Integer>images;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ClickedListener clickedListener;


    public GridAdapter(Context context,List<String>titles,List<Integer>images, ClickedListener  clickedListener ){
        this.titles = titles;
        this.images = images;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.clickedListener = clickedListener;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.intoduction,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.titles.setText(titles.get(position));
        holder.images.setImageResource(images.get(position));

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return titles.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView titles;
        ImageView images;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            titles = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView15);
            images = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
            images.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    clickedListener.onPictureClicked();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**MainActivity2**

```
public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity implements ClickedListener{
    RecyclerView recycleview1;
    List<String> titles;
    List<Integer>images;
    GridAdapter adapter;
    ImageView image;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.intropage);


        recycleview1 = findViewById(R.id.recycleview1);

        titles = new ArrayList<>();
        images = new ArrayList<>();

        titles.add("LATEST MOVIES");
        titles.add("UPCOMING MOVIES");
        titles.add("TRENDING MOVIES");
        titles.add("NOW PLAYING");
        titles.add("RELEASED MOVIES");
        titles.add("HINDI MOVIES");
        titles.add("MARATHI MOVIES");
        titles.add("ENGLISH MOVIES");
        titles.add("TELUGU MOVIES");
        titles.add("TAMIL MOVIES");


        images.add(latestmovie);
        images.add(R.drawable.upcomingmovies);
        images.add(R.drawable.trendingmovie);
        images.add(R.drawable.nowplaying);
        images.add(R.drawable.releasedmovie);
        images.add(R.drawable.hindimovies);
        images.add(R.drawable.marathimovies);
        images.add(R.drawable.englishmovies);
        images.add(R.drawable.telugumovies);
        images.add(R.drawable.tamilmovies);


        adapter =  new GridAdapter(this,titles,images,this);

        GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this,2,GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
        recycleview1.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
        recycleview1.setAdapter(adapter);


    }


    
    }
    @Override
    public void onPictureClicked() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity1.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

**MainActivity1.java**

```
public class MainActivity1 extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.Adapter MovieAdapter;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    String[] movieNameList = {"BHOOT","PANGA","PSYCHO","JUMANJI","DIL BECHARA","BAAGHI 3","THE BRIDGE CURSE","LOST GIRLS","BAD BOYS FOR LIFE",
            "THAPPAD","SADAK 2","TANHAJI","BHEESHMA" };
    String[] movieDescriptionList = {"Horror/Mystery","Sport/Drama","Thriller/Psychological   Thriller","Comedy/Action","Romance/Drama","Action/Thriller",
            "Horror/Thriller","Mystery/Drama","Action/Comedy","Drama","Drama/Thriller","Action/Historical     drama","Romance/Rom-com"};
    String[] movieRatings = {"3.5/5","4.5/5","3/5","4.5/5","4/5","4/5","3.5/5","2.5/5","3/5","5/5","3.5/5","4/5","3/5"};
    int[] movieImages = {R.drawable.bhoot,R.drawable.panga,R.drawable.psycho,R.drawable.jumanji,R.drawable.dil_bechera,R.drawable.baaghi3,R.drawable.bridgecurse,
            R.drawable.lostgirls,R.drawable.bad_boys,R.drawable.thappad,R.drawable.sadak2,R.drawable.tanhaji,R.drawable.bheeshma};


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mainpage);
        recyclerView  = findViewById(R.id.recycleview);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        MovieAdapter= new MovieAdapter(this,movieNameList,movieDescriptionList,movieRatings,movieImages);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(MovieAdapter);
    }




}
```

Comment: Its giving me an error

Comment: Yes! errors are expected as I wrote this whole code without an editor. the mistakes would be in spells. I gave you a whole idea of how to do intent in recyclerview. Can you please show me the errors?

Comment: No Actually I corrected that....Now I am running the code

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.moviebookingapp/com.example.moviebookingapp2.MainActivity2}: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.example.moviebookingapp2.MainActivity2> cannot be instantiated

Comment: I am getting this error

Comment: Can you please upload your code with gist, it would be easy for me to solve that error.

Comment: Yes sure i will upload

Comment: BTW besides MainActivity1 and MainActivity2 should I add any more in manifest file????????

Comment: I have updated my MainActivity2.java code in my main question ............plz check

Comment: please add MainActivity1.java code in your question.